# Minimal cardinality of a vertex $k$-cut of a biconnected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, a *vertex k-cut* of $G$ is a vertex subset of $V$ the removing  of which disconnects the graph in at least $k$ connected  components
(from https://cris.unibo.it/handle/11585/713744).

Given a biconnected graph, the minimal cardinality of a vertex 2-cut is 2, by definition.

My conjecture is that the above property can be generalised to:

> The minimal cardinality of a vertex $k$-cut of a biconnected graph
> is $k$

In other words, can one get $k$ connected components by removing less than $k$ vertices from a biconnected graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question (if I got it right):

> can one get $k$ connected components by removing less than $k$ vertices from a biconnected graph?

Answer:

Yes. Consider the graph $G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{a,b,v_1,...,v_n\}$ and $E=\{av_i,bv_i : i=1,...,n\}$. It is 2-connected. Removing nodes $a$ and $b$ you get $n$ components, where $n$ can be arbitrarily large.